# Request entity too large | http_status 413 | Working with postman but not with code

Tags: ionic-framework, file-transfer, beta, image-upload, ionic4

I am trying to send image file to API using FileTransfer plugin in ionic 4. I am using [FileTransfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) plugin for uploading file to API. Whenever I try to send file to server, it returns me following error.

```
request entity too large
413
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
    at readStream (/home/ec2-user/myjobsiteAPI/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:155:17)
    at getRawBody (/home/ec2-user/myjobsiteAPI/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:108:12)
    at read (/home/ec2-user/myjobsiteAPI/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:77:3)
    at jsonParser (/home/ec2-user/myjobsiteAPI/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:135:5)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/ec2-user/myjobsiteAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (/home/ec2-user/myjobsiteAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
    at /home/ec2-user/myjobsiteAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (/home/ec2-user/myjobsiteAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/home/ec2-user/myjobsiteAPI/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at logger (/home/ec2-user/myjobsiteAPI/node_modules/morgan/index.js:144:5)
```

I tried to uploading image using postman and it's working fine. I am following all the intructions that [FileTransfer](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer) plugin shows in github repo but still it's not working. You can check my code below.

```
const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
let options: FileUploadOptions = {
fileKey: "Photo",
chunkedMode: false,
httpMethod: "POST",
params: {
  "Name": "demo",
  "Addr1": "demo",
  "Addr2": "demo",
  "City": "demo",
  "StateCode": "demo",
  "CountryCode": "demo",
  "ZipCode": "demo",
  "WebsiteUrl": "demo",
  "PhoneNo": "demo",
  "Email": "demo",
  "CompanyDescription": "demo"
}
};
fileTransfer.upload(this.imgData, 'http://*****/*****', options) //this.imgData = "cdvfile://localhost/cache-external/henry-cavill-superman-justice-league.jpg" in my case
.then((data) => {
  console.log(data)
}, (err) => {
  alert("Error Something went wrong Plese try again later!");
})
console.log(this.imgData);
```

Really can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: I have the same problem right now , can you please help me how did you solve it?